# Glassfish JDBC Connection pool throws NoClassDefFoundError CharacterConverterJDBC

Tags: jdbc, glassfish-4

Glassfish version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13)
Oracle Database : 11.2.0.4
JDBC Driver obtained (ojdbc6.jar) obtained from [Oracle download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)  w/c were copied into \glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib  folder.
When I clink on "Ping" it throws error

[image: Error encountered]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Elmer